# Pronouncing an /n/ ending with an extra schwa

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels

I often hear American English speakers pronounce words ending in an /n/ sound with an extra schwa sound after it.

**One example:**

At the end of a sentence, the word's final N with a preceding vowel often comes with an extra, really short vowel (at least in my experience): "pen" sounds like /pennə/. "Ten" and "then" are too.

**Some longer examples:**

"Three plus seven equals ten" or "it's gone." The latter is not ending with N spelling-wise, but is effectively in the same situation.

**Recording:**

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqewbwaUfQU&t=488s) American YouTuber seems to do it. In the linked video, some of the words affected by this possible phenomenon are: "lagoon" at 0:40, "queen" at 2:20, "well done" (the second one) at 4:23, and "option" at 4:49. (Though he *does* speak a little bit exaggeratedly.)

**Question:**

Is this a common thing? Do we have a technical term for this?

Comment: Where are you hearing this (i.e. which part of the English-speaking world)? A full sentence example would be useful.

Comment: For example: "three plus seven equals ten" or "it's gone." The latter is not ending with N spelling-wise, but is effectively in the same situation. English is not my native tongue, but some people (who natively speak English) I've met definitely had this particular pronunciation.

Comment: As I pronounce the **individual** words *then, ten, one, etc.*, or end a sentence with them, I hear a very slight [ə] at the end ten(ə), etc. This is caused by the final consonant being slightly emphasised and pronounced as /ɛn(ə)/ with the consequent /ə/ as the air and tongue position is released. This does not seem to occur when the words are followed by others.

Comment: The only time I hear this in BrE (particularly RP or close to it) is if the speaker wants to emphasise the word. " I said there are **ten**".  In what version of English are you hearing this?

Comment: @Peter Jennings It is AmE that I hear the sound most in speech. As you and Greybeard have pointed out, this only occurs in the end of a sentence or at emphasized words.

Comment: The technical term for this is _epenthesis_, stressed on the second syllable; the adjective form is _epenthetic_, stressed on the third syllable. The little vowel you here is called an _epenthetic schwa_. In the United States, one is often inserted into some vowels, especially in [Northern cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English); and they're quite common in Southern dialects.

Comment: @Qwert Can you find a recording of someone doing this?

Comment: @alphabet For instance, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqewbwaUfQU&t=488s) American YouTuber. Some words are: "lagoon" at 0:40, "queen" at 2:20, "well done"(the second one) at 4:23 and "option" at 4:49. He speaks a little bit exaggeratedly, but this is exactly what I had in my mind.

Comment: My best guess is that this comes from an attempt to "flap" the /n/ sound; this normally happens in words like "winner" and "winter," which can become homophones for some AmE speakers. Normally it's only intervocalic, but if you tried to do so at the end of a word I think you'd get an epenthetic vowel sound afterwards.

Comment: Possibly related; when pilots are communicating via radio, "nine" becomes "niner" to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you have a source for this? I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 2):

John Lawler wrote in a comment:

> The technical term for this is *epenthesis*, stressed on the second syllable; the adjective form is *epenthetic*, stressed on the third syllable. The little vowel you here is called an *epenthetic schwa*. In the United States, one is often inserted into some vowels, especially in [Northern cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English); and they're quite common in Southern dialects.